# Skip inner method calls in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

Let's say, I have methods A, B, C and D.

```
public bool A (int foo)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (foo > 0)
        result = B();
    else result = C();
    D(foo);
    return result;
}
```

I want to write a unit test for A, with calling B or C, but want to skip the D call (because it is a method using external services). Is it possible to skip the D call using some attributes? Or mock the D, substituting it with some fake service?

Comment: You have to *mock* `D`: you can't avoid calling `D` if you enter `A` method

Comment: Yes, you will have to Mock *D* .

Comment: In either case, your wanting to skip the `D` call is the problem itself. You don't want to modify your unit, else it isn't a genuine test. Your test should treat the unit of code as a bit of a black box. "I give it this input, I expect this output."

Comment: Yes, but placing an order in an external system every time I run unit tests does not seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the class that has method `A()` depend upon the external service(s) used by method `D()`. You can use any of the DI patterns to do this, although constructor injection is probably the best starting point.

Once you're in this situation, the external service(s) `D()` depends upon can be faked and injected into the class. Testing is now under your control via the fake(s)'s behaviour.

Something like:

```
class Thing
{
    private IExternalService _externalService;

    public Thing(IExternalService externalService)
    {
        _externalService = externalService;
    }

    public void A() { ... }

    public void D(string foo) 
    { 
        _externalService.DoSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
[Fact]
public void TestThisOut()
{
   var fakeExternalService = new MockFramework.CreateMock();
   fakeExternalService
       .ShouldDoSomethingWhen(s => s.DoSomeStuff())
       .IsCalled();

   var testThing = new Thing(fakeExternalService);

   testThing.A();

   Assert.That(testThing, Did.Some.Thing());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This highlights the importance of designing your code so it is unit testable.  Dependency injection is very useful in this regard. you can then mock dependencies when unit testing.  You may have a communications layer that you could access via an interface ICommunications for example.  Your class would then take a reference to an ICommunications object in its contructor:

```
public class TestableClass
{
    private ICommunications _comms;
    public TestableClass(ICommunications comms)
    {
        _comms = comms;
    }

    public bool FunctionToTest()
    {
        //do something testable

        _comms.SomeFunction();//mocked object in unit tests

        //do something else testable
    }
}
```

Then just create a mock version of comms and pass that in during testing.  You can also add code to your mocked class to emulate certain test conditions - eg for a comms layer receiving some invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock method D. I wrote an example, using Typemock Isolator, take a look:

```
class Methods
{
    public bool A(int foo)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (foo > 0)
            result = B();
        else 
            result = C();
        D(foo);
        return result;
    }

    public void D(int foo) {throw new NotImplementedException();}

    public bool C() { return false;}

    public bool B() { return true;}
}
```

And the test:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestIgnoreD()
{
    //Arrange
    Methods methods = new Methods();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => methods.D(0)).IgnoreCall();

    //Act
    bool result = methods.A(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

I put them all in one class just because I don't know what's going on in your code. Anyway, Isolator rather flexible as it allows to mock almost everything from almost everywhere.